# Accessing Naive Baye's posterior probability in Spark's MLlib

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib

I am trying to access the posterior probability of Naive Baye's prediction with MLlib using Java. As the member variables brzPi and brzTheta are private, I applied a hack to access the values through reflection.

I am using Java and couldn't find a way to use the breeze library with Java. If I am correct the relevant calculation is given through line number 66 in NaiveBayesModel class,

labels(brzArgmax(brzPi + brzTheta * testData.toBreeze))

Here the element-wise additions and multiplication of DenseVectors are given as operators which are not directly accessible in Java. Also, the use of brzArgmax is not very clear with Java for me.

Can anyone please help me convert the above mentioned calculation from Scala to Java.

PS: I have raised a improvement request on Jira for making these variables directly accessible from outside in MLlib.

Thanks, 
Jatin